# how to convert data to byte array in swift and then byte array to integer

Tags: ios, swift

```
if let a = advertisementData["kCBAdvDataManufacturerData"] as! Data? {
    // enter code here
}
```

I am sending a int converted to byte array from a android app to iOS I want to convert that into integer again how to do that in swift

Answer (score 1):

Let extend the Data type:

```
public extension Data {
    
    func to<T>(_ type: T.Type) -> T {
        return self.withUnsafeBytes { $0.pointee }
    }
}
```

Then use it as:

```
data.to(Int32.self)     // convert to int32
```

But be careful when working with data transfer, it's unsigned int or signed int? 32bits or 64bits or 16bits?, sender's endianness and receiver's endianness?